# Laravel Query Builder Output Testing

Tags: sql, laravel, testing, laravel-4

was just wondering if anyone knew of a way to test Laravel Query Builder output and experiment with it.

For example, in PHPMYADMIN you can run and test different SQL queries and see errors and all before you decide to use it in your code. Can this be done with Laravels query builder? Does anyone know of any helpful tools to test the query builders output?

Thanks.

Comment: Make user of `DB::getQueryLog()` as well to see your queries - just added to the answer.

Comment: But this will still need you running queries within a project and SQL errors will be thrown by the Laravel handler...

Comment: make use*. I mean use it in the cli `artisan tinker` like in my answer ;) Anyway mind that you're still working on the real app, so if it's live version, then either use other environment (if possible) or be careful, because you can harm yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `artisan tinker` tool in command line. It's a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) and it does exactly what you want.

Here's example output (allows playing with your app directly and instantly in the cli):

```
~/$ php artisan tinker
[1] > DB::table('some_table')->where('some_field', '=', 'someValue')->groupBy('some_other_field')->toSql();
// 'select * from `some_table` where `some_field` = ? group by `some_other_field`'
[2] > User::where('id', '>', 1)->toSql();
// 'select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null and `id` > ?'
[3] > User::where('id', '>', 1)->get();
// object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)(
// 
// )
[4] > User::where('WRONG', 1)->get();
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'WRONG' in 'where clause'' in ...

[5] > User::where('id', 1)
[5] *> ->orWhere('id', 2)
[5] *> ->latest()
[5] *> ->first();
// object(User)(
//   'incrementing' => true,
//   'timestamps' => true,
//   'exists' => true
// )
[6] > DB::getQueryLog();
// ... all queries will be shown here
```

Comment: Sadly, Tinker doesn't work on Windows systems. Some argue that it works via the Vagrant box of homestead but I have never used Homestead before and don't have the patience right now to start testing how to configure it. Thanks all the same, you've saved a lot from some serious headaches. :)

Comment: I suppose all you need on windows is VM + Vagrant (+ possibly enable Virtualization in BIOS), that's all. This is great tool, so I wouldn't give up just because of that.

Answer (score 2):

you can use https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar, it will gives you all executed queries along with its output and other things.

Comment: my pleasure :). it is very useful tool, but sometime it takes long to render the page as it inspect all queries and other variables.

Comment: Yeah, saw that in the docs. Sadly though its not really what I was looking for since it still needs to be part of a main project. Was looking for a tool, that is kinda removed (separate) from the whole laravel install where i can just play with query builder structures and constructs and try out different types of queries like in the sql section of phpmyadmin. But its all good. Thanks.

Comment: oh!! i don`t know about tools like you describe... but your question is really good, tools like that much exist.